# Seam 2 with Jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, seam

As we know Jboss 7 has implicit modules dependency meaning instead of including the jar file in the WAR package we can instruct jboss 7 to refer it from its implicit modules. This is done by adding scope=provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-excel</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am migrating service from jboss 4 to jboss 7. My service uses Seam 2. In old my service  which is on jboss 4, Seam is used as defined dependency i.e. included in the WAR package. I want to use seam as an implicit dependency in Jboss 7. Does anyone know whether Jboss 7 has seam included as implicit module?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some search I found the instruction in the seam 2.3 distribution which worked for me.

Add below entries in pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
      <type>ejb</type>
   <dependency>
</dependencies>
```